# Perl - finding multiple substrings in a variable?

Tags: perl, substring

I'm very new to Perl and I've been using this site for a few years looking for answers to questions I've had regarding other projects I've been working on but I can't seem to find the answer to this one..

My script receives a `HTTP` response with data that I need to strip down to parse the correct information.

So far, I have this for the substring..

```
my $output = substr ($content, index($content, 'Down'), index($content, '>'));
```

This seems to be doing what it's supposed to be.. finding the word `'Down'` and then substringing it up until it finds a `>`.

However, the string `'Down'` can appear many times within the response and this stops looking after it finds the first example of this.

How would I go about getting the substring to be recursive?

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Use a regex match with the `/g` modifier? `while($content =~ /(Down.*?>)/g) { print $1 }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way like this:

```
my $x="aa Down aaa > bb Down bbb > cc Down ccc >";

while ($x =~/(Down[^>]+>)/g){
        print $1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution,without iteration and just storing what is down.

```
use Data::Dumper;
my $x="aa Down aaa > bb Down bbb > cc Down ccc >";
my @downs = $x =~ m!Down([^>]+)>!gis;
print Dumper(\@downs);
```

Comment: Nice non-recursive example, but it differs a bit from what the original sample does. Having the 'i' flag makes it case insensitive, which might not be desired, and the positioning of the parentheses causes " aaa " to be captured, rather than "Down aaa >" (which may or may not be desired).

I'd propose an edit myself, but apparently edits need to be 6 characters or more (but... it's a regex!).

Comment: Yes, removing Down and > string from regexp was intentional. "just storing what is down" ie. Not stroing the string down and the >.